# How can I know a file's content with chef

Tags: bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to change the gem source using execute resource but I need to do this just one time.

```
remove_rubygems = 'gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/'

execute 'change sources to our gem server' do
  command "#{remove_rubygems} && gem sources -a http://mygemserver"
  creates "~/.gemrc"
end
```

All this because when I execute this resource many times the **.gemrc file** look like it.

```
vagrant@leibniz-app:~$ gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://mygemserver/
http://mygemserver/
http://mygemserver/
http://mygemserver/
...
```

Then, I want mygemserver one time in the .gemrc file.

How can I do it?

Is there any way to know the content of .gemrc before the execute my resource.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `~/` in your path; this is why the `creates` line was not working to prevent the `execute` resource from being run when the file already existed.

```
execute 'change sources to our gem server' do
  command "#{remove_rubygems} && gem sources -a http://mygemserver"
  creates "/root/.gemrc"
end
```

Alternately, if you want to check whether the file contains a specific line:

```
execute 'change sources to our gem server' do
  command "#{remove_rubygems} && gem sources -a http://mygemserver"
  not_if "grep -F -q -e http://mygemserver/ ~/.gemrc" # this uses a shell, so the
                                                      # tilde should work here.
end
```

Comment: For newbies, like me, you might mention that `creates` on it's own will make sure that the file doesn't get overwritten. (Although the manual mentions it already and it sounds logic, ... now :)

Comment: @hek2mgl, thanks -- I've updated this to be more clear, and also to have the `not_if` answer be applicable to a case that `creates` doesn't handle.